# Не получается formdata собрать в array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form

Как собрать форму в массив, чтобы с ней можно было работать, посмотреть все значения в консоли, но при этом отправлять ее через formData ? У меня почему-то в formData пустой объект постоянно, но key, value находит нормально

```js
jQuery(.class).on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formBlock = jQuery('.form')[0];
  var formData = new FormData(formBlock);

  for (var [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(key, value);
  }
  console.log(formData);
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input,
textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" id="qwerty" name="myFormV" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="file_upload">
    <button class="main-btn" type="button"></button>
    <div class="file-form">
      <div id="divOpen"></div><span class="fa fa-times" id="clear_btn"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="fileOpen" value="">
  </div>
  <h4>
    <?php echo $cf_vacanciespage['form_resume_title']; ?>
  </h4>

  <input class="vacancies-form-hidden-input" name="title" type="hidden" value="">
  <input class="form-application__input" type="text" name="Name">
  <input class="form-application__input" type="email" name="Email">
  <input class="form-application__input" type="tel" id="tel" name="Phone">
  <textarea class="form-application__text" name="Message"></textarea>
  <input class="main-btn form-application__submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: а что в консоли показывает переменная `formBlock`?

Comment: `jQuery(.class)` - ??